# When I am copying file from one place I am getting permission denied error

Tags: linux, unix

In Putty when I am copying one file i am getting the below error.

cp: cannot create regular file `/tmp/Header.jspx': Permission denied

And I am trying the below to copy my file to temp folder
iatunl96@vmrodunlv183 /tunl96/otm/product/637/glog/gc3webapp/WEB-INF/ml/jsp/OrderRelease/ULE_ORDER_RELEASE_R2_NEW_ORDERS_ULTRA_COPY1 >cp Header.jspx /tmp

even though I have all the permission for it and I am able to access the same thing for one another file.

Comment: check /tmp folder permissions, usually has 777

Comment: What does `ls -ld /tmp` tell you?  What does `ls -l /tmp/Header.jspx` tell you?  `/tmp` should be 1777 (`drwxrwxrwt`).

Answer (score 0):

> First check if you have read access to your source file and 
>   Check, if you have write permissions to tmp folder

Also if Header.jspx, already exists in /tmp and you dont have privileges on existing file

Comment: Really Thanks for your response